# Algorithm to report products of integers

Tags: algorithm

**Disclosure** This question is based on a question from a CS class. Looking to expand on it though.

The initial question is simply, given a set of `n` integers, report `n` products of `n-1` integers (each time missing a different `n_i`). It is to run in linear time.

For example, a set of `{1, 2, 3, 4}` would report `2 * 3 * 4`, `1 * 3 * 4`, `1 * 2 * 4`, and `1 * 2 * 3`.

The easiest solution (that I can think of) is to simply step through all `n` integers and calculate the product of them all (`1 * 2 * 3 * 4`). Then step through them a second time and, using division, divide the total product by each integer. Reporting the solution each time (`24 / 1, 24 / 2, 24 / 3, 24 / 4`).

The above works and runs in linear time. The professor though suggested we also come up with a way to do it without division. Still no space restriction, just the linear time restriction. I've thought about it but am drawing a blank. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps a better wording would have been "given a set of `n` integers, report `n` products of `n-1` integers"? But yes, the task is to do this without using division. Calculate `n` products, each time without a different n_i.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could calculate an array containing all the leading products first--linear time:

```
1 
1 * 2
1 * 2 * 3
1 * 2 * 3 * 4
```

Then the trailing ones second--this is also linear time:

```
            4
        3 * 4
    2 * 3 * 4
1 * 2 * 3 * 4
```

Any answer can be found directly, or calculated as a product of one item from the first list and one item from the second list:

```
              (2 * 3 * 4)
(1)         *     (3 * 4)
(1 * 2)     *         (4)
(1 * 2 * 3)
```

Comment: I really didnt understand what he wants until I read your answer. +1 nice answer :)

Comment: It looks like he wants the product of all values in the set except for one. This isn't explained well, and the explanation is confused by picking such a small set.

Comment: yeah but your answer was well explained ;)

Comment: I tried to edit the question. Hopefully it made it more obvious what I'm asking.

Answer (score -2):

So what exactly do they want for these products? For example could we have the product `1 * 1` in our solution? If so couldn't you just multiply each number in the array by the first then be done?

Or you can multiply by pairs, for example:
`1 * 2`, `2 * 3`, `3 * 1`
This could be done using a mod operator adding two elements through your array.

Sudo code:

`for i = 0 to array.length 
     print array[i] * array [i+1 % array.length]`

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.